# Execute SELECT for all returned rows from another SELECT within the same query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

With this query:

```
SELECT id FROM org.employees WHERE {some_condition}
```

For every row from the above query, I need to call:

```
SELECT * FROM org.work_schedule(@employeeId, @fromDate, @toDate)
```

where `org.work_schedule` is table-valued function that process all of the employee's available work schedules and constraints and return two DATETIME (start, end) columns representing the availabilities of the given employee for the provided date range.

I am thinking using a cursor on the first query and feed a temporary table that would be returned. Is this the only solution?

The project is in C# and I could also accomplish this in C# directly, but I suspect it would be more optimal to do this entirely in SQL (SQL Server 2008).

This seems localized, and I would generalize the question with :

How can I execute a query (SELECT) for every row returned by another query (SELECT) and return the entire results in one call (dynamically do SELECT UNION SELECT UNION ...)?

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just query your tables directly without the functions? Seems like it would be pretty easy with an INNER JOIN. What does your database structure look like?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `OUTER APPLY` or `CROSS APPLY` instead of a cursor:

```
SELECT *
FROM (  SELECT id 
        FROM org.employees 
        WHERE {some_condition}) A
OUTER APPLY org.work_schedule(A.id, @fromDate, @toDate) B
```